# Prevent WPF window losing focus when a new process starts

Tags: c#, wpf, process, window, focus

I would like to prevent my application losing its focus when I open a link in the browser.
Right now if I click a button then a new link will be opened in the browser on a new tab with this code:

```
Process.Start("chrome.exe", "http://...");
```

But then the window of the browser will come into view, but I would like to have my application keep its focus.

Do anyone know any solution / workaround for this?

Comment: Just a note: if you would call `Process.Start("http://...");` it would open the link in the default browser (which might not be chrome).

Comment: keep its focus or be in front? you can set [`Topmost`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.topmost(v=vs.110).aspx) to `true`.

Comment: After starting the chrome process, put a `Thread.Sleep(2000)`, so that chrome loads the page entirely; then `this.Activate()` will work porperly. The sleep time will vary as per your network speed. Hope this is not the ultimate solution you are looking for.